# What does "ease" stand for?

Tags: javascript, css, button

What does the term "ease" stand for? It appears in code for a spoiler button. Does it refer to margins, gradient, link styling or something totally different?

Comment: You should include the code you're talking about in your question, but it probably refers to the animation style of the element. `ease` is a value for CSS animations.

Comment: [Ease doesn't stand for anything](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ease). In CSS it generally refers to a transition animation.

Comment: It's not even unique to CSS. It's an animation term that's widely used.

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell **ease** is a timing function that is used in CSS with animations and transitions.

For more details go through these links :

[Timing function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/timing-function)

[W3Schools timming function](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition-timing-function.asp)